# Angular checkboxes in ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having some trouble getting checkboxes to work properly for me in an `ngRepeat` directive.

Here's the code:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in arrayOfObjects track by $index">
<td>{= item.email =}</td>
 <td>
         <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.permissions.superuser" ng-value="1">
        </label>
 </td>
  <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.permissions.manage_users" ng-value="1" ng-disabled="item.permissions.superuser">
        </label>
  </td>
  <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.permissions.manage_client_invoices" ng-value="1" ng-disabled="item.permissions.superuser">
        </label>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Notice that `ng-model` is set to a nested object within `item`. I believe this is where Angular is having trouble tracking the clicks.

The expected behavior would be to check any of the checkboxes above independently. However, the actual behavior is that when I select a checkbox (i.e., the checkbox mapped to `item.permissions.manage_users`), then all the checkboxes mapped to `item.permissions.manage_users` get checked.

If anybody can shed some light on the issues, I'd really, really appreciate it.

Comment: can you set up plunk ,with bug  reproduced on em?

Comment: 2nd @KostiaMololkin;  It seems to work fine for me, see my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sy688JxhhfJf5fuNt4nR?p=preview)

Comment: @kablamus it's might be that you using the same `permissions` instance for all items in array

Comment: @Tom There is a slight error in the plunker, which could also be the error in the question itself. Check http://plnkr.co/edit/7GwJ4ejuP5MV4SoL5B3v?p=preview you'll notice that the values are not stored in the predefined object properties, but rather created as new properties. This is because there is an extra `{ item: ... }` which is probably superfluous.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's exactly why.  The `items` in the `ng-repeat` are the objects which have an `item` property.  If you change the `ng-models` to `item.item.[...]` it works, see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UofTGqkSe5sgEJRhflcF?p=preview).  If you have control of the `json` it would make sense not to store an array of objects with one property called item, but rather just an array of objects

Comment: I updated the plunk with a better json representation: http://plnkr.co/edit/9VNEtgskvLleN0uJVTQe?p=preview This is working. I have to look at my code to figure out why my code is not working, but the plunk is.

Comment: Just an update, but there was a problem with the type of object I was iterating through in the ng-repeat. Unsure about how to fix the problem, I reverted to converting the object to json and then back into an object. After the conversion, everything worked as expected.